# Why Azure app service plan restart recently?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have a P1v2 type appservice plan instance.
It runs 3-4 nodejs application services in a containerized environment.
These application services have been completely error free for a whole year, the metrics don't show anything that would overload them, there are no application side errors either.
The appservice plan metrics are also fine.

But lately, once or twice a week I get flooded with alerts because the appservice plan restarts, so all 3-4 appservices too.
And the container startup time is around 3-4 minutes.
And in the meantime the CPU usage increases, plus there are other alerts.

Anyone have any idea what could be the reason for the restarts?

Comment: Do you run multiple instances on App Service? I'm thinking it could be updates to the host VMs/physical servers.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Is it possible to find information on this, or does Microsoft not provide information on this? (I mean about infrastructure updates.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In [service health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview#get-started-with-service-health) , you will be get notified if there are any planned maintenance or any infrastructure update activities .

To know more information about the app service plan restart i would suggest to open discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html) or to file a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) wherein  technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.

You refer the below blog where you can see the sample toasted email notification from Microsoft for a [planned maintenance activity](https://www.techkb.onl/azure-using-service-health-to-alert-against-planned-maintenance/).